# How to remove duplicate from an array

Tags: java

Would you please help me on this? I have a code like this, I have to sort it and then remove duplicates. I've already sorted it but now I'm having a problem removing duplicates. Would you please complete code below for me?
thank guys , it's solved

Comment: Have you tried writing something that does it yourself? Any shown attempt will make people more likely to help fixing the problems with it you may have.

Comment: Do you need to write your own implementation? Else you've got the answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the whole thing in one step with a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

```
list = new ArrayList<>(new TreeSet<>(list));
```

---

For example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(54);
list.add(12);
list.add(62);
list.add(54);
list.add(12);
list.add(43);
list.add(62);

list = new ArrayList<>(new TreeSet<>(list));
System.out.println(list);
```

```
[12, 43, 54, 62]
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, but I don't want to use set list. I want to remove duplicate with compare to and contains methods

Comment: @jamesb Then look at the source code of `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Set` instead of the `ArrayList`. A `Set` removes the duplicates as soon as you add them automatically.

Answer (score 2):

With help of `Set` ,which removes duplicates,your `removeDuplicate`  method turns to

```
 private static ArrayList<Integer> removeDuplicate(ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        return new ArrayList<Integer>(new  HashSet<Integer>(list));

    }
```

Comment: Would not serve much as he does not reassign the list variable.

Comment: Also, this solution fails to maintain sort order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `TreeSet` to accomplish both tasks-sorting and removing duplicates. Make your life easy. Why do you add everything to a list and remove duplicates if there is an easy alternative.

```
Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    set.add(54);
    set.add(12);
    set.add(62);
    set.add(54);
    set.add(12);
    set.add(43);
    set.add(62);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, it's probably easiest to use a TreeSet. However, one of your comments states that you don't want to do this. Maybe you're concerned about efficiency or something. Anyways, to remove duplicates from a pre-sorted collection, you could try something like the following:

```
static <T> void removeDuplicates(Iterable<T> pIterable) {
  final Iterator<T> iterator = pIterable.iterator();
  if (iterator.hasNext()) {
    for (T prev = iterator.next(); iterator.hasNext();) {
      final T current = iterator.next();
      if (prev == null ? current == null : prev.equals(current)) {
        iterator.remove();
      }
      prev = current;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably the right answer since the question mentions sorting first :)